# Google Earth and Skype theme

Tags: 10.10, themes, gtk, qt

I use Google Earth and Skype since version Jaunty, and so far emulation Qt theme for GNOME runs perfectly, but when I use the default theme Ambiance and Radiance in Maverick, both applications look bad. Qt theme is not integrated with GTK. Especially for the Equinox engine (it's cool theme).

To outsmart, I stole the Lucid's Ambiance and Radiance Standard Themes for use in the Maverick.

Is any another solution for the default theme Ambiance and Radiance in Maverick run perfectly on both the application? And especially for the theme Equinox.

Answer (score 5):

Since Version 4.3 Google Earth accepts the parameter `-style GTK|plastique|cleanlooks`.
There is a (rough) way to force Google Earth to use the theme that is set:

1. Install the [getlibs](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474790) deb package (not available in the repositories)
2. Rename/Move all libraries related to Qt from Google Earth by deleting all files beginning with libQt within the Google Earth directory: `sudo mv /usr/lib/googleearth/libQt* $HOME`
3. Install the 32-bit library of libphonon4: `sudo getlibs -p libphonon4`

Comment: Be aware that the content of `/tmp` directory is deleted at boot time, so it is not the safest place to move files you may need again.

Comment: This almost works except the command getlibs can not be found or installed in 12.04 and googleearth will startup but immediately crashes. I can see that the whole theme and fonts have changed though... just keeps crashing

Answer (score 0):

For Skype, you can [change the theme](http://playbreakfix.blogspot.com/2010/04/getting-skype-menus-to-work-nicely-with.html) it uses.

Comment: yes, there is several themes, but if I change with desktop settings or GTK+ the theme look weird. (I select desktop settings or GTK+ because I want to make skype looks unity)