# How can I change Google Earth's "win 98" appearance on Xubuntu?

Tags: google-earth

Installation went as expected, everything works fine except for that ugly win 98 style in the menus. I tried the font solution I found on some forums but it's nothing to do. Any other with this problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7246/google-earth-and-skype-theme

Comment: Followed instructions step by step but googleearth won't launch now. I did not mention I was using 64 bit xubuntu.

Comment: Reinstall it, delete all of it's configuration files, and install qt4-settings form the software center