# How do I fix Google Earth 6.2.2 theme and fonts in 12.04?

Tags: fonts, google-earth, japanese

Here is the problem.

I would like to know how to get Google Earth using better fonts with anti-aliasing for English and Japanese. Don't know what these fonts are but they are hideous and completely different from my system fonts or Libre Office fonts or even QT apps like VLC and MiniTube.

[image]

I'm using 12.04 LTS 32bit and almost had complete success with the 11.10 fix posted here [Google Earth and Skype theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7246/google-earth-and-skype-theme)

the theme and fonts will show up correctly for about 5 seconds before the program crashes.

Comment: This fix almost fixes it but it crashes on startup. I can see that the theme and fonts have changed correctly but .... only after like 10 seconds it crashes. http://askubuntu.com/questions/7246/google-earth-and-skype-theme

Comment: the reason I added 12.04 to the question is because there is an answer for 11.10 that does not work in 12.04